# Is there any way to use XNA 3.1 with Visual C# Express 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xna

Is there any way to use XNA 3.1 with Visual C# Express 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  You can potentially reference and use some assemblies, but to get the full experience including the content pipeline, you'll need XNA Game Studio.  The current release only supports Visual Studio 2008.

However, you can use [XNA Game Studio 4 CTP](http://creators.xna.com/en-US/downloads) with Visual C# 2010 Express.  It is [available here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c8496c2a-54d9-4b11-9491-a1bfaf32f2e3&displaylang=en) (as part of the Windows Phone toolset).

Comment: But it is for Windows Phone development only.

Comment: It's not for phone only, just packaged with the phone development tools. They'll separate them (I assume) when it's time for the proper release.

Comment: Exactly.  Right now, you just have to download the phone kit to get the new XNA studio, but it's good for Windows, Phone, + XBOX dev.

Comment: @Reed - actually, GS 4 is now available in Beta and it does NOT support Xbox dev: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xna/archive/2010/07/12/xna-game-studio-4-0-beta-is-live.aspx

Comment: but I can create xbox 360 games using VS 2010, I think its still 3.1 or whatever, 4.0 comes soon.

Comment: @Spooks: Right now, you need to use VS 2008 to do it.  Very soon, there'll be an updated CTP for 4.0 that'll support this.  @Peter: Thanks for pointing this out  - I had missed that.

Comment: Based on the information available online, it sounds like XNA Game Stduio 4.0's major feature is the ability to develop for Windows Phone 7.  I haven't seen much in the way of information relevant to XBOX or PC developers.